# Second HTTP server with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlets, httpserver

I'm using Spring Boot to create a rest server and everything is going fine. But, now I want to create a second http listener in another port to handle static content such as Html, css, js and etc. I've been reading the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html) but I didn't get it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Static contents can be easily served if you place it static folder in resources.
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-integrating-static-content

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Almost. My pages will be located in a external O.S folder and I already use the project as a rest server. I want to create a new http port listener in the same project  to handle page requests.

Comment: Can you update the question and elaborate where exactly files are and if it can be moved to resources folder etc?